# javascript: navigating between tables in database

Tags: javascript, database

I'm working on an app which will store basic iformation about movies. I've created a database and a javascript function that targets a specific div and prints out the inner html of that div, along with database values.

This is a little sample from that function:

```
function visfilmer(id){
document.querySelector('#film_indre').innerHTML = "";
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM FILMER WHERE id=' + id, [], function (tx, results) {

fjellInfo+= "<div id='tilbake_knapp'><a href='"+ results.rows.item(0).tilbakeknapp+"'  
rel='external'><div id='tilbake'><li>'--------'</li></div></a></div>
</div>";            

document.querySelector('#film_indre').innerHTML +=  fjellInfo;
        window.location = "#page2"; 
        }, null);
        });
}
```

Now i want to add "next" and "previous" buttons that lets you navigate between the tables in the database. A button that sends the user to the next ID value, and another button that sends the user to the previous ID value.

any help, or a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please tell me you're not building out SQL commands in the client and then sending them to the server.

Comment: @VtoCorleone he is probably using websql api,though it's deprecated.